# Guess what am I?

Tags: riddle

> Opulent and Indigent, My Fellows Schlep Each
>
> Once Ruined Some Mend
>   Them!
>
> I Befall In Multitudinous Tints
>
> Every Quartet Year Forge Aureate
>   Me!
>
> 32 Empires Then Combat For Me
>
> But Only A Single Soul Attain Me!

Comment: Is the answer related to a specific area, like a game or a historic figure?

Comment: @WeShall - Probably yes! It might relate to game but not historic figure.

Comment: single soul = team :) ?

Comment: @WeShall - Unfortunately no. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to say it's...

> **FIFA Golden Boot**

Opulent and Indigent, My Fellows Schlep Each

> Rich and poor, everyone has a pair of boots (shoes)

Once Ruined Some Mend Them!

> Sometimes when torn, people mend them

I Befall In Multitudinous Tints

> They come in countless colors

Every Quartet Year Forge Aureate Me!

> Every four years FIFA brings back the coveted boot

32 Empires Then Combat For Me

> Players from 32 countries fight for it

But Only A Single Soul Attain Me!

> But only the top goalscorer gets it

Comment: Thats Correct!!